# How to find the difference of time series data points from the mean and create another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have time series data, I want to append a column that gives the difference between the value(x_i) and the mean(x_avg).

```
df
time    col1    newcolumn
1        30        0
2        20        -10
3        50        20
4        20       -10
```

where mean of col1 = (30+20+50+20)/4 = 30. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply function. But you need to store the average of that column separately.

```py
def diff(row):
    global mean
    return row.col1 - mean

dict = {'col1':[30,20,50,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

mean = df.col1.mean()
df['diff'] = df.apply(diff, axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
   col1  diff
0    30   0.0
1    20 -10.0
2    50  20.0
3    20 -10.0
```

Comment: thank you, but storing the column values in a dict like that may not be feasible in my case because i have thousands of rows of data.

Comment: but i was able solve it in another way. thanks again

Comment: Sure. It's just for demonstration. `apply` method and the custom function `diff` do the trick.